# Do I leave a gap between the exterior wall and insulation for bathroom in workshop?

Tags: insulation

I'm walking into this project blind, as I am not the one who started it. If I staple the insulation to the wood I will be hanging gypsum board on, there will be a large gap between what I assume is the vapor barrier and the insulation. Is this correct, or do I need to double layer the insulation, or put a board between them? The gap will be about 5 in.

This is a sheet metal shop, and I want it to be at least warm enough for the pipes to not freeze and burst. Live in Idaho, gets to negatives in the winter.

[image: Gap between bathroom frame and exterior wall]

[image: front view of gap]

[image: better view of whole wall]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not inherently a problem that there's a gap between your fiberglass batts and the building wrap. However, it *is* a problem if there's enough airflow through that area to scavenge heat from your conditioned space *through* the fiberglass, or around it via any gaps in the blanket installation. Ideally, the cavity in which the insulation resides is effectively sealed from the outside so that the air entrained within it remains undisturbed.

So, if the air in your shop is relatively static, you're probably ok. If there are large overhead doors nearby or fans running or whatever, the effectiveness of the insulation can drop dramatically and you should consider blocking off those areas somehow. What you *don't* want to do is sandwich vapor barriers such that moisture can accumulate and mold develops. Note that the building wrap is not a vapor barrier--it's a *liquid water* barrier intended to allow vapor to pass but act as a drainage plane (and block airflow).

See also: [Can rigid foam board have an air space between it and the studs in a basement wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/139541/35141)

Comment: Apparently someone disagrees with my answer. Feel free to tell us why.